# Android activity calling the same activity with Extras and back button issues

Tags: android, arrays, json, android-activity, android-recyclerview

This is more of a design question regarding Android activities.

**Summary:**

1. Provider provides to RecyclerView X items in categoriesList array list
2. CategoriesList reads array list and shows X items
3. User click on an item which have subcategories
4. Provider overwrites categoriesList array list with Y items
5. CategoriesList reads array list and shows Y items
6. Clicking back button shows X items in a new CategoriesList activity
7. Since array now has Y items an error is thrown or wrong items are shown

**Long version:**

I have categories in a JSON file and articles in separate JSON file per category. In the main activity "CategoriesList" an ArticleProvider is initialized where it reads the categories from "main_categories.json" file and shows the list to the user.

Based on the category selected, I use Extras to pass to the next activity ("ArticleList") the selected category and a list of articles is shown.

Now I have decided to create subcategories. So CategoriesList calls CategoriesList and using extras I read a new file instead of "main_categories.json" and the new subcategories list is shown. When I enter a subcategory the Article list for that subcategory is shown.

My problem is that when I click the back button from the subcategories CategoriesList it goes back all the way to the first screen and the RecylerView shows the main categories. If I click on any of them I get an error about the index because the ArticleProvide which holds the categoriesList has still the subcategories.

---

How to I solve such a problem? Is there anyway to overwrite going back from the subcategories CategoriesList to the main CategoriesList that called it or in general my design is bad?

It's difficult for me to provide code for you because it is too long and as I mentioned this is more of a design question. If needed I will do so.

Also I know that there is a workaround to create a new SubCategoriesList procedure but it will be essentially the same as the CategoriesList so I would like to get this working if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood it correctly, it seems you are either not updating your adapter properly, or not sending the notify state change.

You can capture the back button action by overriding `onBackPressed`, and there send an event or manually updating the adapter. By using an [internal broadcast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html), you can implement some sort of Observer Pattern, allowing your adapter to subscribe to some custom event "back_to_categories", which will be emitted by your fragment on back button.